# Heroku Crashed And Exit 0 But Works on Bash with "python appname"

Tags: python, bash, heroku, crash, dyno

I uploaded a python scripts to heroku.When i start up it the logs print what i code in program but it crashed at the end of all process.

when i use heroku bash and typed python appname it works fine no crashing ?

Do you have any idea why ?

Thank you all you developers

Logginng:

```
2018-10-11T17:43:14.284043+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-11T17:43:18.729869+00:00 app[worker.1]: Done downloading, now converting ...
2018-10-11T17:43:49.428882+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-11T17:43:49.431499+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-11T17:43:49.412511+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

If heroku run with its worker i cant see downloaded file

However,when i use heroku bash with python appname it works fine it downloads what scripts says and when i check filesystem i am able to see downloaded file .

Comment: More info? Paste the stacktrace.

Comment: Please show all the diagnostics you have.

Comment: Also, "and exit 0" would indicate it's not actually crashing, but finishing. Is there an infinite loop in your code that makes it run until it's stopped?

Comment: exit 0 just means that the process was stopped because it was idling. This happens when you use heroku for free(no premium plan).

Comment: "Do you have any idea why?"—no, because you haven't given us anything useful for understanding what the problem is. Please read [ask].

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU How does infinite loop affects the running? I have a free account. The app just won't start at all